# Why does java / android require an empty space at the beginning of an XML element to parse it?

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing

I am parsing an XML file for an Android app I am writing and have noticed that without a leading space the first char is replaced with a blank space.

```
  public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) { //extends DefaultHandler
if(this.in_mytag || this.in_user_id){
  myXMLParser.setExtractedString(new StringBuffer().append(ch).toString());
}
  }
```

I am wanting to use the following format in my XML...

```
<user_id>123</user_id>
```

The string that is returned is " 23" (with the 1 lost and an empty space in the string).
If I use

`<user_id> 123</user_id>`

the result is the expected " 123". What am I missing here? Or is this typical and I will need to alter my XML file.

Comment: Please post an SSCCE (http://sscce.org/) otherwise nobody will be able to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the SAX `characters()` method implementations I've seen have observed the offset and length parameters.

Does this version make any difference?

```
myXMLParser.setExtractedString(new String(ch, start, length));
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the reason why, but i noticed you left out the closing identifier in your xml. `<user_id>123<user_id>` should be `<user_id>123</user_id>`

Comment: Whoops, that's a typo on my posting. My xml file does have the closing identifier. ty